# How to make sure SSL is enabled properly on Active Directory server?

Tags: ssl, active-directory

How to make sure SSL is enabled properly on Active Directory server?

On server itself if I run ldp, I think I can connect on 636 port.

I see something like this in output:

```
ld = ldap_sslinit("localhost", 636, 1);

Error <0x0> = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, LDAP_VERSION3);

Error <0x0> = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);

Error <0x0> = ldap_get_option(hLdap,LDAP_OPT_SSL,(void*)&lv);

Host supports SSL, SSL cipher strength = 128 bits

Established connection to localhost.

Retrieving base DSA information...

Result <0>: (null)

Matched DNs:

Getting 1 entries:

>> Dn:

**** and 10-12 more lines ****
```

Does this mean SSL is enabled properly?

What about errors in 2-4 lines?

Thanks.

Comment: I've followed following process to enable SSL: http://www.linuxmail.info/enable-ldap-ssl-active-directory/

Comment: I think SSL is enabled properly - http://blogs.technet.com/b/yuridiogenes/archive/2008/06/04/iag-2007-authentication-repository.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SSL was enabled.

URLs provided by me in comments have more details.